# how to override Proceed to Checkout button in cart page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

i want to override

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage/link.phtml" />
```

this block i am using thish code in 
**checkout_cart_index.xml** page

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Checkoutbutton" name="test" template="Namespace_Modulename::namespace_modulename/checkoutbutton.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Do you want it only on cart page or minicart as well?

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**

Copy the below file from:

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage/link.phtml

to

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage/link.phtml

And update the text or code according to your requirement.

The above will work for cart page only not for minicart.

**Method 2:**

You can add this in your layout file and use it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Namespace_Modulename::namespace_modulename/checkoutbutton.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Method 3:**(Updated according to the comment)

Create one module with name Vendor_Module and follow the below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create layout file like below under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

and add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Vedor_Module::onepage/link.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2:**
Create block file under:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Checkout.php

and add the below code(for testing):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Checkout extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link {
    // This function is created for testing purpose, you can add more function as per your requirement
    public function getTest(){
        return 'Test Button';
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**
Create link.phtml under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/onepage/link.phtml

and add the below codes(example):

```
<?php if ($block->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <button type="button"
            data-role="proceed-to-checkout"
            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Proceed to Checkout') ?>"
            data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/proceed-to-checkout":{"checkoutUrl":"<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getCheckoutUrl() ?>"}}'
            class="action primary checkout<?= ($block->isDisabled()) ? ' disabled' : '' ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isDisabled()):?>disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?>>
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span>
    </button>
<?php endif?>

<?= $block->getTest(); // Code is added to test if our block is working or not ?>
```

Thats it. Run the required commands and test.

Comment: thank you @Sukumar Gorai can't i override it in my custom module using xml file

Comment: Second method is not working for you?

Comment: in second method can i use my custom block as i shown in question

Comment: Why do you need to change the block class?

Comment: i have to change it as per my requirement condition

Comment: Ok I ll update my answer

Comment: Check my updated answer. Method 3 is block override concept.

Comment: I have exact same requirement but getting error 500 when I go to /checkout/cart/ after following Method 3 changes to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`. Any clues since no errors are reported in system.log or in the browser even in developer mode?

Comment: Any reason for making changes to `checkout_index_index.xml' instead of 'checkout_cart_index.xml' since `checkout.cart.methods` container is defined here?

Comment: My mistake. I have updated it.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, this was very very helpful. I had a typo somewhere in the custom Link Block code, which was causing the error. I have followed Method 3 with below entry in checkout_cart_index.xml to override Onepage Link Block and link.phtml and it's working well.

`<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
 <block class="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Onepage\MyLink" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Vendor_Checkout::onepage/mylink.phtml">
 </block>
</referenceContainer>`

Comment: Hi @SukumarGoraiI have followed your answer but not calling from my custom code.  can u advise what layout handle we need to use it here checkout_cart_index (or) checkout_index_index ?

Comment: Its for checkout_cart_index. Also check your existing handler if it has the codes which is related to onepage/link.phtml

Comment: @SukumarGorai I am using the same code but still calling from core link.phtml and i am trying to override from my custom module. can u advise

Comment: i tried with method 3 and it is working fine with magento 2.3.5-p2 but not working with magento 2.3.1

Comment: I ll update the answer

Comment: @SukumarGorai it will be great help if you update this.
Thank you in advance